# Using Grunt with ES modules in Node

Tags: gruntjs, es6-modules

Is it possible to use Grunt with ES modules in Node? I'm in the process of transforming a large node app from CommonJS to ECMAScript modules. However, the project contains a lot of custom grunt tasks, which are giving me issues since it appears Grunt refuses to run ES modules.

**package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "type": "module",
  "dependencies": {
    "grunt": "^1.4.1"
  }
}
```

**gruntfile.js:**

```
import outputTask from './outputTask.js';

export default function(grunt) {
    grunt.registerTask('output', outputTask);
}
```

**outputTask.js:**

```
export default function() {
    console.log('Here is some text..');
}
```

This simplified example produces the error `Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: Gruntfile.js`.